# Create galery with flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make a gallery with pictures on a flask website, I have all my pictures in a folder and I wonder if there is any way to display all the pictures in that folder easily using HTML and python. I am pretty new to coding and web design so hopefully, someone will answer:)

The solution I'm currently using is:

Html document:

```
<a class="IMGLIST" href="../static/Gallery/kaja1.jpg"><img src="../static/Gallery/kaja1.jpg"> 
        <a class="IMGLIST" href="../static/Gallery/kaja2.jpg"><img src="../static/Gallery/kaja2.jpg">
        <a class="IMGLIST" href="../static/Gallery/Karin.jpg"><img src="../static/Gallery/Karin.jpg">
        <a class="IMGLIST" href="../static/Gallery/laftahyte.jpg"><img src="../static/Gallery/laftahyte.jpg">
        <a class="IMGLIST" href="../static/Gallery/Stange.jpg"><img src="../static/Gallery/Stange.jpg">
```

This works but it is not an effective way to add al the pictures manually like this especially when I'm planning to add lots:)

Comment: Use Jinja template and loop over the images list. see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Answer (score 2):

Since you said flask I'm assuming you have a route that responds with the HTML file.
You can use [flask templates](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/templates/) (you keep your HTML file but get to have python logic in it) and have a for loop that loops through an images list that you pass when rendering the template.

The HTML file would have

```
{% for image in images %}
    <a class="IMGLIST" href="{ image }"><img src="{ image }" /></a>
{% endfor %}
```

And your flask route would return something like

```py
return render_template('index.html', images=list_of_images)
```

More information on flask templates can be found [here](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-tutorial-templates/)